# Legendre polynomial on interval [a,b] other than [-1,1]

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, legendre-polynomials

My question is simple, that

The Fourier Legendre series make use of Legendre polynomial defined on [-1,1]
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-LegendreSeries.html

What if the variable x that the function consists of is outside of [-1,1] as [a,b]? Then one should anticipate that the corresponding Legendre polynomial be defined on [a,b], correct?

This brings to my question: how to find the Legendre polynomial over the interval [a,b]? I know that for the case of [0,1], the corresponding Legendre polynomial is called the shifted Legendre polynomial. But how to generalise the same idea to [a,b] in a direct, simple, yet computational efficient way? For instance, is it possible to perform a direct transformation using the Legendre polynomial defined on [-1,1] then convert it to [a,b]?

Thank you!

Comment: why is it called Fourier-Legendre series ? [because of the orthogonality ..](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFourierSeries.html)

Comment: That's exactly what i thought initially. I performed a change of interval as is done on Gaussian quadrature. However I did't get the right result. My suspicion is the transformed Legendre polynomial by means of change of interval doesn't preserve the orthogonality on [a,b] my programming may have error and my suspicion could be wrong and hence my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Polynomials are defined everywhere.  But if what you want are orthogonal polynomials on the interval $[a,b]$ analogous to the Legendre polynomials which are orthogonal on $[-1,1]$, you may want to take 
$$f_n(x) = P_n\left(\frac{2x-a-b}{b-a}\right)$$ where $P_n$ are the Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Are you sure of this formula? The inner product that the legendre basis is orthongonal under is $\langle p(x), q(x) \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} p(x) \cdot q(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ so naturally we would choose our inner product on $[a,b]$ to be $\langle p(x), q(x) \rangle = \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \cdot q(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ and your formula does not appear to be orthogonal under that inner product. Using the inner product I gave, your first two basis polynomials would be $\{1, x - \frac{a+b}{2} \}$

Comment: Yes, and those are indeed orthogonal under this inner product.

Comment: @RobertIsrael by your formula. $f_0$ corresponding to $P_0 = 1$ is $\frac{2x-a-b}{b-a}$ and $f_1 = \frac{2x^2 -ax -bx}{b-a}$ corresponding to $P_1 = x$, but $\int_{a}^{b} \frac{2x-a-b}{b-a} \cdot \frac{2x^2 -ax -bx}{b-a} \ \mathrm{d}x \neq 0 $

Comment: I see your misunderstanding.  $P_n(t)$ means evaluation of the function $P_n$ at $t$, not multiplication of $P_n$ by $t$.

Comment: Ah I see. Good work, I retract my dissent. (: This is actually much cleaner then the formula I derived a while back. +1

Comment: And what about Taylor expansion (coefficients) for such functions? Do you have any idea how to get them?